# yii2 customized CRUD under version control

Tags: yii2

Is there some possibility to write customized CRUD not in vendor directory  as I want put it under git version control. I tried  like here  https://github.com/yiisoft/yii2-gii/blob/master/docs/guide/topics-creating-your-own-templates.md. I can't find link to CRUD under gii-generators.

Comment: In the link you pasted, there's param to set template's directory. Create template in your project, and point to it in this param.

Comment: Thanks, it helped